# How to use options in a Jenkins scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using a Jenkinsfile with a Scripted Pipeline.
I would like to modify the `buildDiscarder` option for this pipeline, but I can't get it working.
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options

How to define pipeline options in a scripted pipeline?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't use `options` as that is a specific piece of the [*Declarative Pipeline*](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline) feature set.

For the multibranch-style builds you should use the [`properties`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-multibranch/#properties-set-job-properties) step. The [*Snippet Generator*](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator) can help you find the correct syntax to help build out pieces of your Jenkinsfile. For example, in this case you would use the `buildDiscarder` symbol that resolves to that configuration option.

```groovy
properties(
    [
        buildDiscarder(
            logRotator(
                daysToKeepStr: '7',
                numToKeepStr: '25'
            )
        )
    ]
)
```

The `properties` step will be evaluated when your `Jenkinsfile` is executed, so that is when the configuration will be effective. I tend to put the `properties` at the top as a "best practice".
See the full options on your instance's *Snippet Generator* for the other things you can keep (such as artifacts).

Comment: Please extend your answer for this newbie question - where in the scripted pipeline does the properties() block appear? Inside the node {} block or before it?