# Conditional expressions in blocks other than `stages` with declarative Jenkins pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

We have a lot of declarative Jenkins pipeline code that is used for a certain Jenkins instance in our main environment, and now we want to have a second Jenkins instance for an isolated environment that should use the same pipelines, but behave a bit different with a few tweaks here and there.

The way we're going to distinguish between the two instances is by defining a global environment variable in the Jenkins master, and with that we can have conditional stages, and conditional steps with `when` and `script` blocks under the `stage` block. (e.g. `if (env.ENVIRONMENT == "ISOLATED") { <do something else> }`)

How can we achieve something similar with the `parameters {}` and `options {}` blocks? I know we can use "variables" with shared libraries to provide, say, different options to a `choice` parameter, but we want to be able to have 1 less / 1 more parameters in some cases that are irrelevant / relevant only in a certain environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert your Pipeline to a scripted Pipeline you should be able to do this pretty easily.

```
if (env.ENVIRONMENT.contains("ISOLATED")) {
    properties([
        parameters([
            string(name: 'Cloud', defaultValue: 'AWS', description: 'Cloud Type')
        ]),
        // This is a option
        buildDiscarder(
            logRotator(
                daysToKeepStr: '7',
                numToKeepStr: '25'
            )
        )
    ])
} else {
    println "If not set something different"
}


pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Hello") {
            steps {
                echo "Building Something"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47778019/how-to-use-options-in-a-jenkins-scripted-pipeline) on how to generate option snippets.